# xcode9: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate... Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, simulator, xcode9

Apologies if this is an obvious mistake (new to coding!) but I'm having a couple issues.

1: The following error appears when I want to load Simulator in Xcode 9:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate...
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

This issue only appeared after I added a Label for "Cat Years" title and changed the background colour in Main Storyboard.

2: When Simulator did work before the above changes, the cat (imageView) would not appear in the Simulator?

Thank you for any suggestions in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func getAge(_ sender: Any) {

        if let age = ageTextField.text {

            if let ageAsNumber = Int(age) {

                let ageInCatYears = ageAsNumber * 7

                resultLabel.text = "Your cat is " + String(ageInCatYears) + " in cat years!"



            }
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you entered any Int value in `ageTextField` without spaces?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653771/uipicker-error-on-swift#comment78266823_45653771 (just my comment, you need to use the debugger, get the real error message and then it should be easier to understand what happened)

Answer (score 0):

You get "SIGABRT" errors when you have an outlet which is disconnected from a view. You can check by clicking your view controller in your storyboard and going to connections on the side panel. If you see an extra/duplicate outlet there, this is likely what is causing your problem.

In your example, you likely have either an extra outlet on the text field or the outlet in your code was referencing a different text field and the field is no longer in your storyboard.